# Get data from 2 tables, of the same ID with $pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

I'm trying to get some dataa from a table, and search for another field on other table by the id i got on my first query

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx;charset=utf8', 'xxxxx', 'xxxx');
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM oc_store') as $row) {
    echo $row['name'].' '.$row['url']. ' '. $row['store_id']; 
}
```

This works fine. But i have to

```
select value from oc_setting where store_id == oc_store.store_id and key == config_logo
```

and echo all togheter, like:

```
echo $row['name'].' '.$row['url']. ' '. $row['store_id']. ' ' .$row['value'];
```

I tried nested foeach (silly me :P) and also with the LEFT JOIN, but i'm afraid i couldn't get it working, maybe i'm missing the right sintax for that.... Any helps? Thank you all

Comment: Use `=` instead of `==` in where condition `select oc_setting.value from oc_setting, oc_store where oc_setting.store_id = oc_store.store_id and oc_setting.key = oc_setting.config_logo`

Comment: left join will select all values, not just matches. Right join is the way to go

Comment: @KrishR, don't encourage him to do a join in php

Comment: @AdrianBR, What you mean `to do a join in php`?

Comment: @KrishR , I did it, still can't complete both selects togheter, but thanks for spotting that

Comment: `select oc_setting.*` use this to get all values from table `oc_setting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably mean you need

```
select se.value, st.name, st.url
FROM
oc_setting  se
INNER JOIN
oc_store st
ON st.store_id = se.store_id and st.key = 'config_logo'
```

Comment: I used it like foreach($db->query('select ..... but got  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Also, i have to get st.name and st.url too

Comment: got it working with: query('SELECT se.value
FROM oc_setting se
INNER JOIN oc_store st ON st.store_id = se.store_id
AND se.key =  \'config_logo\'') , it returns the se.value but i need st.name and st.url ,any ideas how to select them too?

Comment: oops, that was easy, i just had to put them after 'select'. like this: SELECT se.value, st.name, st.url
FROM oc_setting se.............

Comment: yep, thought you'd just insert the needed fields, as to me it wasn't clear which table had which ^^. Have a +1

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work with left join?

I'm genuinely new here and I'd love to give it a shot.

```
SELECT st.*, se.value FROM oc_store st LEFT JOIN oc_setting se ON st.store_id = se.store_id AND se.key = config_logo;
```

That's it IMO. Hope it works :)

NOTE: I'm not sure about key = config_logo as where is config_logo is coming from or where it belongs from those two tables. Key, I'm assuming it belongs to oc_settings.

Comment: he needs an inner join to filter for the results he needs :)